# What do you call this relation between pre-orders?

Tags: order-theory

Let $\sqsubseteq_1,\sqsubseteq_2$ be two pre-orders.
Say that $\sqsubseteq_2$ *perfects* $\sqsubseteq_1$ if:

- $a \sqsubset_1 b$ implies $a \sqsubset_2 b$, and
- if $a$ and $b$ are incomparable according to $\sqsubseteq_2$, they are incomparable according to $\sqsubseteq_1$

You can see that "perfecting" is a pre-order on pre-orders, whose top elements are linear orders. Notice that "perfecting" is incomparable with inclusion (aka relation refinement).

Is "perfecting" a standard notion?

I checked the two books called "Ordered Sets" (Harzheim and Schroeder) but I had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

These are fully *faithful functors* if you view preorders as categories. 
(A preorder is the same as a category such that for any objects X and Y there is at most one morphism from X to Y.)